# Caption does not work with wrapfig

Tags: formatting, captions, wrapfigure

The following code does not output the caption correctly, font appears in normal size, and "Figure" is not boldfaced.

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \vspace{-50pt}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{figure.png}
  \end{center}
  \caption{bla bla bla}
  \vspace{-20pt}
  \label{fig4}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

I use at the beginning

```
\documentclass{IOS-Book-Article}
\usepackage{times}
\normalfont
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{graphicx}     

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
```

Comment: Please read section 3.1 of `l2tabu-en`. Thou shall not use `center` in float environments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `caption` package does not change font size or series of captions and their labels by default. Specify formatting options as desired.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% Remove [demo] to show actual graphic

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{figure.png}
\caption{bla bla bla}
\end{wrapfigure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: where do oyu insert the figure here?

Comment: I use `\rule` as a placeholder for `\includegraphics`.

Comment: sorry, I am new to latex, could yo modify your magnificent example so that it includes also a figure loaded from disk?

Comment: @flow: Example edited.

Comment: yeah, now how can I tell caption to get the same samller font and boldfaced type for "Figure" as usual?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Try to replace `\usepackage{caption}`with `\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}` in your code.

Comment: ok now it works !

Comment: and what about martin schroeder note on center?

Comment: Take a look at my code example -- I replaced `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}` with `\centering`. Also, read [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651/510) question.

Comment: ok. it is clear that you are the master, thanks!